# Diffeomorphism have the property that the determinant of a jacobian matrix is 1. is the derivative of diffeomorphism bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\phi:R^2\to R^2$ is smooth diffeomorphism and the determinant of a jacobian matrix is 1. Then is  $D\phi$ bounded?
In other words,
If $\det D\phi=1$, then $\|D\phi\|_{L^\infty}$ is bounded.

And If we replace $R^2$ for $R^2-0$, is $D\phi$ still bounded?

Comment: What are your thoughts about the problem? What did you try to find a counter example?

Comment: By bounded, do you mean "bounded linear map"?

Comment: The Jacobian at each point is a square matrix, and any square matrix can be the Jacobian of some map. So your question reduces to a question about matrices. Namely, is there a uniform bound on the set of all matrices with determinant 1?

Comment: Note that even the formulation of the problem is unclear (not that it really affects the answer). My interpretation is: Assuming that $det D\phi(x)=1$ for all $x\in R^2$, you are asking if $||D\phi(x)||$ is bounded on $R^2$.

Comment: Yes. You are right(Moishe Kohan)

Comment: Hint: Try to find a counter example to the claim.